# Can anyone tell me which ajax varibale responsible for database update in this code?

Tags: php, ajax

[Here is the code](http://pastebin.com/9n9imQ16)..

I would like to clone that code for another module called "reputation".

[This is what i done so far](http://pastebin.com/Xj9TSGeh). But when i click update it actually updates points instead of reputation.

[Here is the difference of two files](http://pastebin.com/diff.php?i=Xj9TSGeh).

I never worked with ajax. So I'm confused in that ajax part.

So can anyone tell me which lines responsible for database update?..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php is doing the update with the parameters sent to it.

here's the part of the code.

```
 jQuery.post('<?php echo bloginfo('url').'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'; ?>',
     {
         action: 'cp_manage_form_submit',
         user_id: user_id,
         points: points
     }
```

and here's the code which sets the "points" variable:

```
 points = jQuery(this).children('input[name=cp_manage_form_points]').val();
```

it means get the value of `<input name="cp_manage_form_points">` inside the submitted form.

Comment: first points is the key of it, and second is the variable. its like $_POST["points"] = points;